# How are security restrictions applied in a directory structure?

Tags: security

Let me be a little more specific.

I'm working on a web app that provides management of documents and we need to apply security settings to the folders and documents. The folder structure exists entirely in the app (so there is no folder structure on a disk anywhere).

Now, assume that I have a folder structure like this ...

```
root
-- DirA
---- DirA1
-- DirB
----DirB1
```

If this were windows, and a user had rights to change the security settings on all folders in the structure except DirA and opted to make a change to root and all its children, what folders would be effected?

My gut feeling is root, DirB and DirB1 but I'm not sure.

The point is, I want to duplicate the functionality - in terms how /how/ settings are applied - to my app. So, I'm just looking for a simple explanation.

--
Simple of Grantham

Answer (score 0):

When you to set security rights for a user/group in Windows, you also specify whether those rights are inherited to all subfolders.  So, if you give the user the right to modify rights in root, you would have to make those rights non-inheritable or they could modify DirA as well.  However, Windows doesn't grant rights to modify security settings for a folder unless the user has "Full Control" over that folder.  I believe this means that if the user has full control to root, he could delete DirA and add a new DirA, with whatever rights he chooses.  To get a better feel for how directory rights work, right-click on various folder icons in Windows XP, choose Properties, then select the Security tab.  Study this pane, and then click on the Advanced button to see how rights are inherited.  By clicking on the various buttons you will see that by selecting certain rights, such as Full Control or Modify, all other rights are automatically included.